# What's the fastest way to get the word out of the middle of a sentence of three? / manipulating strings

Tags: javascript, string, methods, angular7

I have several strings that I have to modify in different ways

```
const string1 = 'PACK Nº1 compressed :';
const string2 = 'PACK Nº2 compressed :';
const string3 = 'PACK Nº3 compressed :';
const string4 = 'PACK Nº4 compressed :';
const string5 = 'PACK Nº5 compressed :';
```

I must transform them all so that they look like this

```
', Pack Nº1 compressed'
```

For this I have been getting the first and last word and transforming them and also eliminating the elements that I do not want

```
    const phrase = 'PACK N°1 comprenant :';
    const result = phrase.replace(' :', ''); //to eliminate : and blank space

    const firstWord = result.replace(/ .*/,'');
    const lastWOrd = result.split(" ").pop(); // to get first and last word

    const lastWordCapitalized = lastWOrd.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + lastWOrd.slice(1); // to capitalize the first letter of the last word

    const lowerFirstWord = firstWord.toLowerCase();
    const firstWordCapitalize = lowerFirstWord.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + lowerFirstWord.slice(1); //to capitalize the first letter of the first word
```

now that I have them separately I wonder what would be the quickest way to get the second word of the original sentence to put them all together... or if there is a more efficient way to perform the desired conversion

thank you in advance for your help

Comment: To get the second word you could use `str.split(' ')[1]`. I don't think there is any need to use `.replace()`. Wouldn't this be sufficient?  https://jsfiddle.net/3rror404/0L15kgd9/7/

Comment: @Turnip great, thank for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have commented each part in the snippet below, all you need to do is loop over your strings.

I have assumed you meant to capitalise each word as that was what your code was showing, even though your example desired output did not show this.

Also it wasn't clear if you wanted to keep the "º" or replace it with a "°" as you used both within your question. I went with the former, if you need help with changing that let me know.

```js
var phrase = 'PACK Nº1 compressed :';
phrase = phrase.replace(" :",""); // get rid of the unwanted characters at the end
phrase = phrase.toLowerCase() //split by words and capitalise the first letter of each
    .split(' ')
    .map((s) => s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1))
    .join(' ');

phrase = ", " + phrase; //add the leading comma

console.log(phrase);
```

Comment: I figured there had to be a faster and more efficient method but I didn't see how! Thank you so much!!